# Where do I control sitemap for Docusarus?

Tags: docusaurus

I've checked `docusurus.config.js` and I can not see that sitemap plugin is installed but sitemap.xml exists in build directory.

What defines parameters how is sitemap generated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the documentation of the docusaurus:

> If you use the preset @docusaurus/preset-classic, you don't need to install this plugin as a dependency.

You can configure it like this

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@docusaurus/preset-classic',
      {
        sitemap: {
          changefreq: 'weekly',
          priority: 0.5,
          ignorePatterns: ['/tags/**'],
          filename: 'sitemap.xml',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

Check this [reference](https://docusaurus.io/docs/api/plugins/@docusaurus/plugin-sitemap) for more info.

Comment: I don't have that in my docusarus config file, but I still get sitemap.xml in my build folder. How could that be?

Comment: The `sitemap.xml` is *always* generated automatically. Those parameters are just to configure it. *Side-note: the sitemap is a requirement for SEO and for search engine like Algolia. So this may be the reason for it be generated automatically.*

Comment: I did a search inside the source-code of the docusaurus for the sitemap. Check inside your `./node_modules/@docusaurus/` for the folder `plugin-sitemap`.

Comment: Yes, it is there. Thanks!