# How to get Docusarus sitemap in local build?

Tags: javascript, docusaurus

I've had one sitemap question before ([Where do I control sitemap for Docusarus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73900280/where-do-i-control-sitemap-for-docusarus)), so this is kind of an extension to that question. On the documenataion page (https://docusaurus.io/docs/api/plugins/@docusaurus/plugin-sitemap) it says "This plugin is always inactive in development and only active in production because it works on the build output.". Is there a way to bypass this so that the sitemap is also served when I run the build locally or start the site using `npm run start`?

When I visit http://localhost:3000/docs/sitemap.xml I get 404 page